# Android studio - Problemas de diseño ¿Como evito que los componentes se superpongan al escribir?

Tags: android, android-studio, component, android-bottom-nav-view

Estoy trabajando en un nuevo proyecto y en un fragmento tengo un "Edittext" en el que se requiere escribir, pero al darle clic para escribir sale el teclado nativo de android y se superponen los componentes de esta manera.

(Aquí el diseño esta bien)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Aquí sale el teclado y se superponen los componentes tapando el "Edittext")
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hace falta información me comentan xD soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca la propiedad

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

en tu `AndroidManifest` y coloca tu contenido del fragmento dentro de un `NestedScrollView` y esto debe solucionar el problema.